# both MySql and mysqli dont work

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have problem with one small script for inserting into db:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO players ( 
             'ign', 'level', 'str', 'dex', 'int', 'con', 'luck', 'datum', 'clasa' ) 
          VALUES 
             ( '$ign' , '$level' , '$str' , '$dex' , 
               '$int' , '$con' , '$luck' , '$date' , '$class' )";
if(mysql_query($sql2)) {
    $tmp = "Added player to DB";
} else {
    $tmp = mysql_error();
}
```

I use this on many websites , but here its not working.
I get error like: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near.....

then I tried this approach:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mirdel_wiki", "mirko77", "mirdel_wiki");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    } else {
        $tmp = 'Connection working';
    }

    if($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO players ( ign, level, str, dex, int, con, luck, datum, clasa ) 
                    VALUES ( 'bwanana' , '333' , '333' , '555' , '444' , '666' , '555' , '12514' , 'warrior' )")) {
        $tmp = "Added player to DB";

    } else {
        $tmp = "ERROR";
    }
```

Connections is good, but on insert I get always error. Btw, Values should be vars, but it is not good with this numbers also :/

Where are errors, what Im missing???

Comment: wrap `int` in  backticks its a reserved word. And in the first query you are using single quotes for column names remove them and just add backtick for `int`

Comment: You are using single quote where you should have back ticks.

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to use descriptive field names. Nothing to be gained using the shortest name for a column you can think of.

Comment: thx for all help, its working. I removed single quotes and changed column name to other than int, Thank you for fast help

Comment: this is final lok of query:
  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO players ( ign, level, str, dex, inte, con, luck, datum, clasa ) 
      VALUES 
         ( '$ign' , '$level' , '$str' , '$dex' , '$int' , '$con' , '$luck' , '$date' , '$class' )";

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO players ( 'ign', 'level', 'str', 'dex', 'int', 'con', 'luck', 'datum', 'clasa' ) VALUES ( '{$ign}' , '{$level}' , '{$str}' , '{$dex}' , '{$int}' , '{$con}' , '{$luck}' , '{$date}' , '{$class}' )";
```

Try this for the first query